# Django models. Associating tuples in multiple model classes and admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

A newbie Django question about associating data in models.

I have three tables, CarMake, CarModel and Driver.

CarMake has several car brands in it.

CarModel has several models of each of those brands.

- My first question is how do I associate multiple car models per car
  brand inside a models.py class?
- Secondly, in the admin page (and eventually via the views) how do I
  associate those car makes and car models with a driver. So in Admin,
  If I make a new Driver, I choose driver_name, then select from a
  dropdown list car_make, then based on what Make I selected, choose
  from a dropdown list of car models.

  For example in admin:

  ```
    driver name =    "john" 

    driver car = -> Toyota    -> Avalon
  ```
- Third, how would I select multiple car makes and multiple car models
  per make for a driver. So if a driver selects Volkswagon model cars, they can select 'Golf' and 'Passat' from the dropdown list as their cars.

Here is some basic code I was considering:

```
from django.db import models

class CarMake(models.Model):
    MAKE = (
        ('Ford'),
        (''Toyota'),
        ('Volkswagon'),
    )

    car_make = models.CharField(choice=MAKE)

class CarModel(models.Model):
    MODEL = (
        ('Ford'
            ('Focus'),
            ('Explorer'),
            ('F150'),
        )
        ('Toyota'
            ('Avalon'),
            ('Highlander'),
            ('Tundra'),
        )
        ('Volkswagon'
            ('Golf'),
            ('Jetta'),
            ('Passat'),
        )
    )

    car_model = models.CharField(choice=MODEL)

class Driver(models.Model):
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    driver_car = '''choose make and model'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Django Models Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) to find out how to create your `models.py`. I see the exact idea of what you're getting at in this file but you're combining two things.

`models.py` should contain *the entities and how they are connected* ***not*** *the entities and the possible instances of these entities*. `models.py` defines the database structure **not** its contents - this is important to note.

As a few pointers:

- `CarModel` should have a `ForeignKey` of the `CarMake` table. This will define the relationship between a car and who makes it. Then you will need to define another field to hold the model of that car. I'm not sure how to enforce only selecting cars from a certain manufacturer (but that's a question in it's own right) - maybe this should be in the front-end logic?
- `Driver` should also have a `ForeignKey` of `CarModel` to define what car this driver drives. **note** how many cars can one driver drive? You'll need to decide if they can only drive one or if they can drive many.

Have a good read at the documentation before going on, it'll help you a great deal more than anything else and is always the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described, it sounds like you want a one to many relationship between CarMake and CarModel. e.g. One CarMake can have multiple CarModels, but one CarModel *can not* have multiple CarMakes. Here is some code to get you started:

```
# In app/models.py
class CarMake(models.Model):
    name = models.CarField(max_length=30)


class Car(models.Model):
    model = models.CarField(max_length=30)
    make = models.ForeignKey(CarMake)


class Driver(models.Model):
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

**Creating Make Models**

```
make = CarMake(name='Toyota')
make.save()

car = Car(make=make, model='Avalon')
car.save()
```

**Registering in Admin**

```
# in app/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import CarMake, CarModel, Driver

admin.site.register(CarMake)
admin.site.register(CarModel)
admin.site.register(Driver)
```